# Are reflections possible in the Air-Space interface?

Tags: optics, reflection

Total internal reflection is a thing. And the refractive index of Vacuum is obviously lesser than air. So is it possible for me to see myself reflected in the sky if I go to the end of the atmosphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no sharp boundary to the atmosphere. The refractive index changes gradually. So you will not see any reflection because there is no boundary.